# PHP Time Remaining in Current Day

Tags: php

How can we find out how many time remains to end the current day  from current time[date('Y-m-d H:i:s')] in PHP.

Comment: If you are going to display that to your visitors, you need to take care of timezone differences.

Comment: ..continuing my comment: The easiest way to take care of timezones is to do the calculation in Javascript. Since it's client-side it uses the visitor's computer time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example with a combination of [`mktime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and [`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php):

```
$left = mktime(23,59,59) - time() +1; // +1 adds the one second left to 00:00
```

**Update:**

From Simon's suggestion, `mktime(24,0,0)` works too:

```
$left = mktime(24,0,0) - time();
```

Comment: You should add 1 second, then your result is perfect.

Comment: Would mktime(24,0,0) also work? I don't have the possibility to test it now.

Comment: @Simon: I just tried it (for fast testing I use codepad.org) and it works indeed :)

Comment: May not work if dailight saving time kicks in that day. You sould use the DateTime class.

Comment: Note that $left is a value in seconds. To get hh:mm:ss output, use this code `sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($left/3600),($left/60%60), $left%60);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$time_in_seconds = (24*3600) - (date('H')*3600 + date('i')*60 + date('s'));
```

Calculates the total seconds of one day and subtracts the seconds passed until the current hour of the day.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, for anyone interested (takes care of timezone differences) :

```
var now=new Date();
var d=new Date(now.getYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),23-now.getHours(),59-now.getMinutes(),59-now.getSeconds()+1,0);
document.write(checkTime(d.getHours()) + ':' + checkTime(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + checkTime(d.getSeconds()) + ' time left');

function checkTime(i) { 
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}
```